# How do we get today's value and last 7 days value in the same row in the daily report?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 with 3 columns, `Name`, `Date` and `Today's values`. I can show easily in the report but we need to see "Last 7 days total" values in the same report as well. I mean each row should be represented like name, date, Today's Value and Last 7 Days Total.

Can you please help with the query?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Firstly I would recommend to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and look around the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Review your materials and give a try yourself. [Search the solution thoroughly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), and if you're still stuck [post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be very glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t.Name, t.Date, t.Value, 
    (SELECT SUM(s.Value) 
     FROM your_table s 
     WHERE s.date <= t.date 
       AND s.date > DATEADD(DAY, -7, t.date
    ) AS last_7day_value
FROM 
    your_table t
WHERE 
    t.date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the quick answer. We need to add "s.Name = t.Name and " after the where and then it works. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't use sorted windowed aggregates to generate your totals, you can do this without a sub-`select` or non-equijoin logic through a self-`join` and `cross apply`:

```
declare @t table(ValueName varchar(10),ValueDate date, ValueAmount int);
insert into @t values
 ('Name 1','20190101',4)
,('Name 1','20190102',3)
,('Name 1','20190103',8)
,('Name 1','20190104',6)
,('Name 1','20190105',9)
,('Name 1','20190106',6)
,('Name 1','20190107',3)
,('Name 1','20190108',2)
,('Name 1','20190109',1)
,('Name 2','20190101',3)
,('Name 2','20190102',7)
,('Name 2','20190103',6)
,('Name 2','20190104',8)
,('Name 2','20190105',8)
,('Name 2','20190106',7)
,('Name 2','20190107',6)
,('Name 2','20190108',9)
,('Name 2','20190109',3);

select t.ValueName
      ,t.ValueDate
      ,t.ValueAmount
      ,t.ValueAmount + isnull(sum(p.ValueAmount),0) as SevenDayTotal
from @t as t
    cross apply(values(dateadd(day,-1,t.ValueDate))
                     ,(dateadd(day,-2,t.ValueDate))
                     ,(dateadd(day,-3,t.ValueDate))
                     ,(dateadd(day,-4,t.ValueDate))
                     ,(dateadd(day,-5,t.ValueDate))
                     ,(dateadd(day,-6,t.ValueDate))
                     ) as d(d)
    left join @t as p
        on t.ValueName = p.ValueName
            and p.ValueDate = d.d
group by t.ValueName
      ,t.ValueDate
      ,t.ValueAmount
order by t.ValueName
      ,t.ValueDate;
```

## Output

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
| ValueName | ValueDate  | ValueAmount | SevenDayTotal |
+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
| Name 1    | 2019-01-01 |           4 |             4 |
| Name 1    | 2019-01-02 |           3 |             7 |
| Name 1    | 2019-01-03 |           8 |            15 |
| Name 1    | 2019-01-04 |           6 |            21 |
| Name 1    | 2019-01-05 |           9 |            30 |
| Name 1    | 2019-01-06 |           6 |            36 |
| Name 1    | 2019-01-07 |           3 |            39 |
| Name 1    | 2019-01-08 |           2 |            37 |
| Name 1    | 2019-01-09 |           1 |            35 |
| Name 2    | 2019-01-01 |           3 |             3 |
| Name 2    | 2019-01-02 |           7 |            10 |
| Name 2    | 2019-01-03 |           6 |            16 |
| Name 2    | 2019-01-04 |           8 |            24 |
| Name 2    | 2019-01-05 |           8 |            32 |
| Name 2    | 2019-01-06 |           7 |            39 |
| Name 2    | 2019-01-07 |           6 |            45 |
| Name 2    | 2019-01-08 |           9 |            51 |
| Name 2    | 2019-01-09 |           3 |            47 |
+-----------+------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detail explanations. It works. However, if I have more than 1 data in a day with different hours, It creates more than 1 records for each day in the output. It does not work well. Can you please test it with the more than 1 data in a day. Regards

Comment: Surely you can work that out yourself?  You need to group by the date of the datetime, so do that in the code example I have given you.